# Event management for two or more features

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

How can I do to code with Openlayers 3 events management.

I have two features to manage and I have not found how to use ol.interaction.Select.

But maybe this is not the right method.

example with Openlayers2

```
select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature([layer_1, layer_2]);
layer_1.events.on({"featureselected": do something...... });     
layer_2.events.on({"featureselected": do something...... }); 
map.addControl(select); 
select.activate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With OL 3 you can add an `array` of layers to the [`ol.interaction.Select`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) constructor like this:

```
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select({
  layers: [vectorLayer1]
});
var selectInteraction2 = new ol.interaction.Select({
  layers: [vectorLayer2]
});

map.addInteraction(selectInteraction);
map.addInteraction(selectInteraction2);

// do the same with other interaction
selectInteraction.on('select', function(evt) {
    if(evt.selected.length > 0){
    // do something
  }
});
```